# RedirectToAction for index to go to example.com/controller/id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, redirecttoaction

We are using a controller which has an "Index" action:

```
[Route("")]
[Route("Index/{id:int?}")]
[Route("{id:int?}")]    
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
         var viewModel = new GroupViewModel();
....
        return View("Index", viewModel);

    }
```

We can get to this action by using `example.com/my/` or `example.com/my/index` or `example.com/my/index/1`.  This works as we want.  Now we want to redirect to this using the `example.com/my/index/1` syntax.

When we execute this line:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "My", new { id = 3 });
```

It will redirect using this url:

`example.com/my?id=3`

We want it to use `example.com/my/index/1` instead.

Does anybody know of a way to force `RedirectToAction` to use this convention without the question mark?

**Updated 5/2/17 to correct controller names per comments below**

Comment: Is **Controller** is the real nam of your controller ?

Comment: No.  Sorry for the confusion, I updated the name to MyController in the example above.

Comment: Assuming MyController is your real controller name, it should be `return RedirectToAction("Index", "My", new { id = 3 });`

Comment: I have updated the name of the controller per your comments.  Sorry for the confusion.  Thanks to both CodeNotFound and Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell which route template you need to use for generating the URL for the redirection. For the moment you haven't an URL template that can generate a URL like **/my/index/1** which is `"My/Index/{id:int?}"`

First,add that route template to your action and set the `Name` property of that route like this:

```
[Route("")]
[Route("Index/{id:int?}")]
[Route("My/Index/{id:int?}", Name = "MyCompleteRouteName")]
[Route("{id:int?}")]    
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
     var viewModel = new GroupViewModel();
....
     return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

Second, you must `RedirectToRoute` instead of `RedirectToAction`. `RedirectToRoute` let you choose which template you want by giving its name.

So you must call this line :

```
RedirectToRoute("MyCompleteRouteName",  new { id = 3 });
```

Instead of

```
RedirectToAction("Index", "My", new { id = 3 });
```

Comment: This is what we are looking for.  Thanks @CodeNoteFound.